# vba multiplicaton off by 2 decimals when multiplying by 1 or 2 but not >3

Tags: excel, vba

I have no idea what's going on here and had to split apart the vba to make sense of it.

```
the value of textbox8 is 0.832676943005964
commandbutton4 multiplies textbox7 * textbox8



when textbox7 = .15 the answer is 0.124901541450895 which is correct
when textbox7 = .1 the answer is 8.32676943005964E-02 which is wrong
when textbox7 = .05 the answer is 4.16338471502982E-02 which is wrong
```

wth is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is correct it just is in scientific notation `8.32676943005964E-02` = `.0832676943005964` then is what the `E-2` is.

Comment: in VBA `CDec(0.832676943005964 * 0.1)` will produce  0.0832676943005964

Comment: ... how are those answers wrong? What were you *expecting* exactly?

Comment: that simple wow. Thanks!